# Java Class variable Error?

Tags: java

```
public class class2 {
    static int number3 = 86;

    public static void Whale() {
        static int number4 = 86;

    }

}
```

why is it i get an error on line number 5 and not line number 2? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Whale` is a method, and you can't define a static field within a method. You can have a local `number4` like

```
public static void Whale() {
    int number4 = 86;
```

or a `static` field like

```
static int number4 = 86;
public static void Whale() {
```

finally, by convention class names should start with a capital letter (`CamelCase`) and method names with a lower case letter (`camelCase`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that java doesn't support static local variables unlike C/C++. But in some cases Closures may help you for your goal.

Try these some sources for Closures -

- [GoogleTechTalkByNeal Gafter](https://youtu.be/0zVizaCOhME),
- [AnotherBog](https://youtu.be/0zVizaCOhME),
- [java.dzone.com](http://java.dzone.com/articles/whats-wrong-java-8-currying-vs)